# Hololens: Failed to export the spatial mapping database and system map

Tags: hololens, mrtk

everyone! I encountered a problem when developing the HoloLens app:

I have 2 hololens.

I want to copy one of mapping data to other hololens with [device portal > Map manager > Export System Map & Spatial Mapping Database].

It says "Failed to export the spatial mapping database and system map, check if the device is sleeping :[object Object]"

However, [Export System Map & Anchors] was successful.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRWTj.png)

What should I do?
It confused me for a long time.

***Notes***
I have a project with WLT.
I installed the app and setting up markers like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mixed-reality/world-locking-tools/documentation/howtos/samples/spacepin
I want to copy the data to other hololens so that I could have the same result in other hololens.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, this is a known issue, and we will try to track it. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution!
Reenable Device Portal permissions in hololens [Setting > Update & Security > For developers].
The problem will be solved.
Thanks, everyone:)))